# Unity3d select empty gameobjects in scene

Tags: unity, selection, gameobject

I have a pathing system that I am creating in Unity. When you add nodes to denote the path, I create a empty GameObject and render it in OnGUI as a square. The problem that I have is clicking on the object in the scene view. I am trying to figure out what would be the best way to click the Node, so that I can move and rotate the Node.

I had some ideas, like:

1. Creating a Cube or some other GameObject with a mesh, and change the layer to Node. Then make the camera cull out the Node layer.
2. Only in editor mode, create a temp asset and delete it before runtime.
3. Do a raycast and see what objects are near the click, then pick the closest one.

I have a feeling that I am putting to much thought into it, and suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to [extend](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/gui-ExtendingEditor.html) the Unity editor. Looks like you can use the Handles class to create custom handles for your objects too.